# How to change scaling of x/y axis to plot outliers in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot, scatter-plot, anomaly-detection

In a set of datapoints I am trying to graph on a scatterplot, there are a couple of huge anomaly points. For reference, most values range between 0-100 but occasionally there is an anomalous point of 100000. Because of this, when I graph on a scatterplot, box plot, or any plot that is, it zooms out so much to fit in all the points that the 99% of the points that range between 0-100 just looks like a tiny dot. Is there any way I can scale it so that the first 99% of the points are scaled accordingly and have the scale skip to the anomaly point's value so it fits in the graph?

Here is how the graphs look:

Box Plot:
[image: Box Plot]

Scatter Plot:
[image: Scatter Plot]

Answer (score 0):

Use the plt.axis() function with your limits.

plt.axis([x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max])
where x_min, x_max, y_min, and y_max are the coordinate limits for both axe

Answer (score 0):

You can set x/y axis scale to log or just set limit on x/y (with `plt.xlim(0,200)` for example) to hide anomalies from your chart:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set_style('whitegrid')

plt.figure(figsize=(20,12))
data = [1,2,3,4,5,55,1,6,7,24,67,33,41,75,100_000,1_000_000]
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.title('basic boxplot')
sns.boxplot(x=data, flierprops=dict(markerfacecolor='green', markersize=7))
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.title('log x axis')
b = sns.boxplot(x=data, flierprops=dict(markerfacecolor='red', markersize=7))
b.set_xscale('log')
plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.title('basic scatter')
hue = ['outlier' if i > 100 else 'basic sample' for i in data]
sns.scatterplot(x=data, y=data, hue=hue)
plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.title('log x/y scatter')
s = sns.scatterplot(x=data, y=data, hue=hue)
s.set_xscale('log')
s.set_yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah that makes sense! However, is there any way to **include** anomalies in the graph without having to squeeze the rest of the graph to such a tiny graph? I do want to keep anomalies and also change the color of the anomaly points so it is easily visually represented on which points are anomalies

Comment: I showed you the way, how to include anomalies without squeezing the chart - **you have to use log scale for axis**. I've added code with color changing.

Answer (score 0):

The [`outset` library](https://github.com/mmore500/outset) can help make multiscale visualizations to account for large-magnitude outliers.

## Example

Plot all data, including outliers and then a zoom panel showing only non-outliers.

[image: example with outset axes]

```py
# adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72778992/17332200
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import outset as otst
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Data Preparation
xdata = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 55, 1, 6, 7, 24, 67, 33, 41, 75, 100_000, 1_000_000]
ydata = xdata[1:] + xdata[:1]  # slightly vary from x coords for nice plot
outlier_thresh = 200

data = pd.DataFrame({"x": xdata, "y": ydata})
data["outlier"] = (data["x"] > outlier_thresh) | (data["y"] > outlier_thresh)

# Initialize an OutsetGrid object
outset_grid = otst.OutsetGrid(
    data=data,
    x="x",
    y="y",
    col="outlier",  # split plots based on outlier status
    col_order=[False],  # only magnify non-outlier data
    marqueeplot_source_kws={  # style zoom indicator elements
        "leader_stretch": 0.5,
        "leader_stretch_unit": "inches",
    },
)

outset_grid.map_dataframe(sns.scatterplot, x="x", y="y")

otst.inset_outsets(outset_grid)  # rearrange move outset axes on top of source
outset_grid.marqueeplot()  # render marquee annotations
```

This two-axes grid can easily be rearranged into an inset.

[image: example plot with inset]

Just add the following line before showing or saving,

```py
# rearrange to move outset axes on top of source
otst.inset_outsets(outset_grid)
```

`outset.inset_outsets` provides kwarg options to fine tune inset placement, if desired.

## Installation

To install the outset library, `python3 -m pip install outset`.

## Additional Features

In addition to data-oriented zoom area selection shown above, the library also provides an explicit API to manually specify zoom areas as well as many styling and layout options.

Refer to the outset [*quickstart guide*](https://mmore500.com/outset/quickstart.html) and [*gallery*](https://mmore500.com/outset/gallery.html) for more info.

***Disclosure**: am library author*